# Gaze tracking with a webcam (openCV and C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, estimation, eye-detection

I'm trying to realize a tool that returns the 2D coordinates of the point that the user is looking at. To do that I'm using openCV, c++ language and a low-cost webcam. I have the 2D coordinates of the center of the two pupils (leftPupil, rightPupil) but I don't know how to find the user's gaze. 
I suppose that some information is missing but I don't know the right formula to estimate the gaze.

Is it mandatory to add a laser to get the distance of the user from the webcam? Must I analyze the geometric form of the pupil (if they are circles or elipses)? In this case, how can I detect the case in which they are eliptic or round?

Thank your for your ideas

Comment: check https://github.com/trishume/eyeLike as a start point.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Andrey Smodorov. That is indeed the starting point from which I began. Thanks to that I can detect the 2D coordinates of the center of the eyes. What I need now is some way to estimate the user's gaze and, unfortunately, the trishume's implementation doesn't  trak it yet...

Comment: You can try isophoto curvature gaze tracker + Kalman filter. I did it it worked fine for me you can check here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDm82agY_k0. It not open source but you can estimate results.